# How to Connect Excel table to SQL table

Tags: sql, excel, sharepoint

I have a Excel worksheet which contains a table which i have exported from SharePoint, but with this i have made it so the excel file refreshes with new data from SharePoint. Now i need to create a connection between this excel file and a SQL Database.

Most things i have looked at have only told me how to pull data from a SQL table to excel where as i want to do the opposite. I have also tried to connect the excel file to SQL by using third party application but this still doesn't work

Any Ideas how to do this?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-for-excel.html Or more tortuous, export excel data to csv, import csv to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

BIRT is a freeware reporting tool that can use Excel as a report source.

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

Answer (score 0):

This is frequently done using SSIS (DTS in earlier versions) in SQL Server. It is easy to connect to a spreadsheet using the visual interface. It must be remembered that the name of the sheet always ends with a "$" in any import. SSIS and DTS also support variables that can be used to change the name of the spreadsheet as needed on the fly. This blog entry discusses some of the problems: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/bradleyschacht/2012/03/23/excel-source-the-output-column-failed-because-truncation-occurred/

**Edit:** Finally found a tutorial for SQL 2005. It hasn't changed much since then. See:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server-2005-using-integration-services/205